# How to know which button I clicked in flask?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I my current project, my index page show several torrents with a button for each to start or stop the torrent.

I create the page with a form and a loop, so the forms have always the same names. But I need to know which button the user has clicked to know which torrent to stop !

Here is the template :

```
{% block content %}
 <h1>Hello, {{user}} !</h1>

 {% for torrent in torrents %}
      <form action="/index" method="post" name="torrent">
           {{torrent.control.hidden_tag()}}
           <p><a href='/torrent/{{torrent.id}}'>{{torrent.name}}</a> is {{torrent.status}} and {{torrent.progress}} % finished. <input type="submit" value="Start / Stop">
           </p>
      </form>
  {% endfor %}
```

Here is the view :

```
  @app.route('/index', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
  def index():
  user = 'stephane'

  torrents = client.get_torrents()

  # for each torrent, we include a form which will allow start or stop
  for torrent in torrents:
    torrent.control = TorrentStartStop()
    if torrent.control.validate_on_submit():
        start_stop(torrent.id)

return render_template("index.html", title = "Home", user = user, torrents = torrents)
```

So, how do I know which torrent the user want to stop/start ?

Comment: Can we see the code for `hidden_tag`?

Comment: Thomas is right, since you open a form per torrent the whole problem is really non-existant, since you can simply submit the info hash in a hidden field. My answer assumes a single form for the whole page or listing.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `hidden_tag` creates a `hidden` input with name `torrent_id` and value the ID of the torrent, you will find the torrent id in `request.form["torrent_id"]`:

```
from flask import request

....
torrent_id = request.form["torrent_id"]
```

Comment: The hidden_tag is just a csrf protection tag. But I will try something using your advice.

Comment: @22decembre Just replace the `a` with `<input type="submit" name="torrent_id" value="{{ torrent.id }}"/>` and you'll be good.

Comment: Ok, so this solved the "which button is clicked" problem, and by the way, I learn about the button I didn't know (I knew the input, not the button).

But now comes the fact that I get as many answer as I have torrents inline because of the loop ! So how do I launch the function only one time ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a HTML `<button type="submit">` element and either set the `value` to the info hash, or set a `formaction` URL that includes the info hash (`formaction` is HTML5 only).

Answer (score 0):

u can use active button status with js , if someone clicked button and change its css class to active button and than check which button is active and get its informations.

this is js code :

```
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myDIV");

var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
 btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
this.className += " active";
 });
  }
```

and this is css for buttons :

```
  .btn {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    cursor: pointer;
    }


   .active, .btn:hover {
    background-color: #666;
    color: white;
    }
```